# AUTOML with dynamic data does not produce predictionengine

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, prediction, automl, microsoft.ml

I need to automatically predict the machine costs based upon a csv file with header of which the number
of columns and the names of the columns are only known once the file is read.
Below is a small example of the dataset, but the number of columns can be huge! (sometimes 100 or  It can not be hardcoded into the program (different names and unknow column count).

```
    /*
     Trainfile.csv
     Costs,Mach1,Mach2,Mach3,Maint1,Maint2,Maint31,Inst1,LM
     12.3, 3.2, 5.5, 5.3, 12, 53, 72, 16,2
     17.4, 1.2, 6.2, 5.6, 12, 64, 75, 19,7
     13.9, 3.0, 6.6, 5.2, 11, 44, 42, 12,4 
      9.4, 2.2, 4.5, 4.0, 12, 54, 52, 13,0
       
     Trainfile.csv other time could be 
     Costs,Mach13,Mach2,Mach3,Maint1,Maint12,Maint5,Inst1,LM,XM
     12.3, 3.2, 5.5, 5.3, 12, 53, 72, 16,2, 11,2
     17.4, 1.2, 6.2, 5.6, 12, 64, 75, 19,7, 16,1
     13.9, 3.0, 6.6, 5.2, 11, 44, 42, 12,4, 12,2
      9.4, 2.2, 4.5, 4.0, 12, 54, 52, 13,0, 16,3
      
     Trainfile.csv other time could be 
     Costs,Mach6,Mach3,Maint11,Maint12,Maint3,Inst1,LM,XM
     12.3, 3.2, 5.3, 12, 53, 72, 16,2, 11,2
     17.4, 1.2, 5.6, 12, 64, 75, 19,7, 16,1
     13.9, 3.0, 5.2, 11, 44, 42, 12,4, 12,2
      9.4, 2.2, 4.0, 12, 54, 52, 13,0, 16,3
```

I need to train, evaluate and predict.I store all Feature importances in a database to see wheter
the data should still be collected in the factory)
Also i should be able to save the Best model and later on load it again to use it for predictions.
I can ofcourse choose to rename the features and put a 1000 features in the class an fill the ones
not in the csv with 0; But that's a ugly workaround in my opinion.

the code goes haywire on creating the Prediction engine; not finding a column name. like Mach1

running VS2022, .Net6, The nuget Libs: Microsoft.ML 2.0.1 and Microsoft.ML.AutoML 0.20.0 ML
tried many solutions given but the all die during the process.
Any one that can make a prediction engine here ??

I've been googling, edging, binging, Chatgpting for a few days now but no avail.

I tried many solutions given but they all die during the process.

So any suggestions/improvements for me?

---

Code so far:

---

```
       private async Task TrainModelAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                var context = new MLContext(seed: 0);

                // Load the data
                var Options = new TextLoader.Options();
                var TColumns = new List<TextLoader.Column>();

                Options.Separators = new char[] { FieldSeperator };
                Options.HasHeader = true;
                
                foreach (var column in HeaderRow)
                {
                    TColumns.Add(new(column, DataKind.Single, TColumns.Count));
                }
                Options.Columns = TColumns.ToArray();

                var textLoader = context.Data.CreateTextLoader(Options);

                IDataView dataView = textLoader.Load(DatasetFile);
                 
                var dataSchema = dataView.Schema;

                // Split the data into a training set and a test set
                
               var trainTestData = context.Data.TrainTestSplit(dataView, testFraction: 0.2, seed: 0);
                
                var trainData = trainTestData.TrainSet;
                var testData = trainTestData.TestSet;

                 ColumnInferenceResults columnInference = context.Auto().InferColumns(DatasetFile, labelColumnName: LabelName, groupColumns: true);

                var pipeline = context.Auto().Featurizer(dataView, columnInformation: columnInference.ColumnInformation)
                     .Append(context.Auto().Regression(labelColumnName: columnInference.ColumnInformation.LabelColumnName))  ;  

                AutoMLExperiment experiment = context.Auto().CreateExperiment();

                experiment
                    .SetPipeline(pipeline)
                    .SetRegressionMetric(RegressionMetric.RSquared, labelColumn: columnInference.ColumnInformation.LabelColumnName)
                    .SetTrainingTimeInSeconds(10)
                    .SetDataset(trainData);

                TrialResult experimentResults = await experiment.RunAsync();

                var BestModel = experimentResults.Model;

                var Rsquared = experimentResults.Metric;

                context.Model.Save(BestModel, dataSchema, ModelFile); // save for later test

                var transformedData = BestModel.Transform(trainData);
                var pfiResults = context.Regression.PermutationFeatureImportance(BestModel, transformedData, permutationCount: 3);

                List<(string Key, double RSquared)> Importances = new();
                foreach (var item in pfiResults)
                {
                    Importances.Add((item.Key, item.Value.RSquared.Mean));
                }

                foreach (var pair in Importances.OrderByDescending(x => x.RSquared))
                {
                     System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"{pair.Item1}\t{pair.Item2}");
                }

                // Load Trained Model
                DataViewSchema predictionPipelineSchema;
                ITransformer LoadedModel = context.Model.Load(ModelFile, out predictionPipelineSchema);
                var predictionEngine = context.Model.CreatePredictionEngine<InputFX, OutputFX>(BestModel);

                foreach (var checkRow in context.Data.CreateEnumerable<InputFX>(testData, false))
                {
                    var prediction = predictionEngine.Predict(checkRow);
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Predict1: ${prediction.Prediction:F3}; vs {checkRow.Label:F3}");
                }
 
                // try if we can Create a PredictEngine form the saced file ;
                var Context2 = new MLContext();
                ITransformer  Model2 =  Context2.Model.Load(ModelFile, out var _);
                predictionEngine = Context2.Model.CreatePredictionEngine<InputFX, OutputFX>( Model2);

                foreach (var checkRow in context.Data.CreateEnumerable<InputFX>(testData, false))
                {
                    var prediction = predictionEngine.Predict(checkRow);
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Predict2: ${prediction.Prediction:F3}; vs {checkRow.Label:F3}");
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex) { System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message + " " + ex.StackTrace.ToString()); }
        }
```